# SQL generating red underscores erroneously

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

Writing code in SQL Server 2016.  It is generating the red squiggles under certain columns which I have referenced, and when I hover over these with the cursor, it says, "Invalid column name x"

However, there is no reason why these columns should be invalid.  And when I press the execute button, the query executes without any apparent issues!

How is this possible?  Is this a bug in version 2016?

Comment: Can you add the code to your question?

Comment: that is just intellisense not working correctly, you can ignore it

Comment: When you update the database schema in any way, the sql server 'intellisense' it has doesn't update.  I'ts just a display error. Sometimes restarting the server fixes this.

It should be fine to just ignore though, I've gotten to used to ignoring those warnings :)

Comment: Try pressing Ctrl + Shift + R to refresh the Intellisense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its a normal behavior as the IntelliSense does not recognize the objects that are not cached.

I use the Refresh cache option in Edit menu each time I see this.

Edit -> IntelliSense -> Refresh Local Cache

Comment: If you use SQL Complete, you can get to this option a little faster from the SQL Complete menu

Comment: CTRL + SHIFT + R is the shortcut to refresh the cache as well. A bit faster than going to the menu.